# how to run spring boot project-test.jar file from command line?

Tags: java, spring-boot, netbeans

Following is my test class file

```
@RunWith( SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.class )
@SpringBootTest(webEnvironment = SpringBootTest.WebEnvironment.RANDOM_PORT)
@ContextConfiguration(classes = {Application.class, SecurityConfig.class})

public class PolicyTest {
```

After running a build i got two jar files, one is src jar and another is test jar file...I want to run project-test.jar from command line

Note: developed this project on Netbeans IDE